# VS Code ftp-sync: sync prepare in progress... forever and nothing happens

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp

Using the ftp-sync vscode extension, when I try syncing local to remote, I see the message
`Ftp-sync: sync prepare in progress...` for a long time and the local contents don't appear in the explorer sidebar.

Here is my config

```
{
  "remotePath": "./",
  "host": <host>,
  "username": <username>,
  "password": <password>,
  "port": 22,
  "secure": true,
  "protocol": "ftp",
  "uploadOnSave": true,
  "passive": false,
  "debug": false,
  "privateKeyPath": null,
  "passphrase": null,
  "agent": null,
  "allow": [],
  "ignore": ["\\.vscode", "\\.git", "\\.DS_Store"],
  "generatedFiles": {
    "extensionsToInclude": [""],
    "path": ""
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your FTP port to 21.

You can also try deleting all the settings you aren't using and changing secure to false.

```
{
  "remotePath": "./",
  "host": <host>,
  "username": <username>,
  "password": <password>,
  "port": 21,
  "secure": false,
  "protocol": "ftp",
  "uploadOnSave": true,
  "ignore": ["\\.vscode", "\\.git", "\\.DS_Store"],
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).